# Kriging in QGIS 3.4 Problem with Variogram Model

Tags: qgis, kriging

In QGIS 3.4.13 - Madeira there seems to be a bug in the Ordinary Kriging Modul (Processing Toolbox > SAGA). When I enter the modell "1600000*x+19202*x^2" QGIS will add a second "^" leading to wrong results. Am I doing something wrong? Is this bug known?

[image]

[image]

Comment: In python exponent is implemented with two *; not with ^ character.

Comment: @ xunilk: thanks, but that does not work.

Comment: You can write the equation in this style `a * x + b * x * x`. (It works for me). Out of curiosity, what kind of data are you trying to perform Kriging? I do not know real use case of this equation, and if I am not mistaken `b` got to be negative number.

Comment: @ Kazuhito: thank you, that worked fine!

Comment: Thanks @Rob Let me put it as an answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The equation can be put in this way:

```
a*x + b*x*x
```

so your case would be:

```
1600000*x + 19202*x*x
```

Hopefully sometime in near future it accepts `^` to express *power*.